# Error in the template with Django : can I make arithmetic in if statement

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, python-2.7, django-templates

I would like to make a pagination with Bootstrap : a new page every 10 new field in data.

file.html

```
{% for d in data %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
      <ul class="pagination">
    {% endif %}
    {% if (forloop.counter % 10) == 0 %}
        <li><a href="#{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ forloop.counter % 10 }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

output I would like that => [Bootstrap pagination](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination-default)

But Django give me an error for this :
    {% if (forloop.counter % 10) == 0 %}
TemplateSyntaxError :/

I don't know how to do except create my own filter or add a filter, but i would like to know first if i can do in the template first.

PS: I use Django 1.5 and I can't upgrade it.

**Edit:**

Finally I use this condition:

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:'10' and forloop.counter|divisibleby:'5' and forloop.counter|divisibleby:'2' %}
```

Like that I know when I have a 10 multiple.

Comment: Use the paginator it is way easier than inventing the wheel yourself, from django.core.paginator import Paginator ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus (%) operator is not available in django templates. However, you can use the `divisibleby` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) template filter, something like

`{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}`

Comment: Thanks, I will look i that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the paginator, your QuerySet are not evaluated for the hole table, just the number you need to build the page, and it offers properties that you can use in the template like (page_range, next_page_number, has_next, etc.)
here is the code withe BootStrap 2 and django.core.paginator:

```
   <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
        <ul>
            {% if MYDATAENTIRES.has_previous %}
                <li>
                    <a href="?page={{ MYDATAENTIRES.previous_page_number }}">{% trans "Précédent" %}</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% for i in MYDATAENTIRES.paginator.page_range %}
              <li {% ifequal MYDATAENTIRES.number i %} {{ 'class="disabled"' }} {% endifequal %}>
                  <a href="?page={{ i }}">
                    {{ i }}
                  </a>
              </li>     
            {% endfor %}
            {% if MYDATAENTIRES.has_next %}
                <li>
                    <a href="?page={{ MYDATAENTIRES.next_page_number }}">{% trans "Suivant" %}</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```